# Recursive Regex expression to split expression by character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a regex expression to split the following type of data:

```
<exp>(;<exp>)*
```

and receive a list of every *exp* but not the delimiter ';'.

So far I have **([^;])(?:;([^;]))** but this regex stops at the first *exp* after ';'. Is there any way to make the lookahead infinite?

Here is a concrete example:

```
23;hello;2452;ad34aa;bye
```

I want to get:

```
[0] = 23
[1] = hello
[2] = 2452
[3] = ad34aa
[4] = bye
```

I apologize if this question has been answered but I have been unable to find a working expression. If it has please tell me the link.

Thanks for taking the time to read this :)

Comment: Wouldn't split by `;` give you that?

Comment: `split(';')` or `match(/[^;]+/g)`

Comment: "Recursive", "lookahead" - these terms are misused in the question.

Comment: Just so I do not make a similar mistake again, what words would you suggest to define this problem/question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [String#split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
var array = '23;hello;2452;ad34aa;bye'.split(';');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');

// as mentioned from Avinash Raj
var array2 = '23;hello;2452;ad34aa;bye'.match(/[^;]+/g);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array2, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: also `str.match(/[^;]+/g)`

Comment: The String.split assumes the use of javascript language, I was looking for a regex expression, the edition was exactly what I was looking for, thank you.